# match string with if statement

Tags: php

I am trying to match two strings and if there is a match state that a match was found. The strings I am comparing are dates using the following code.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.feedburner.com/2dopeboyz');
foreach($feed->channel->item as $item) {
    $title = $item->title;
    $description = $item->description;
    $pubdate = $item->pubDate;
    $newDate = date("mdY", strtotime(str_replace("UT", "", $pubdate)));
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $today = date("mdY");

    if ($newdate == $today) {
        echo 'Match!';
    } else {
        echo "No Match!";
    }
}
```

My problem is that ever string returns no match even when the strings are the same. How can I get this working?

Comment: Have you tried echoing out both $today and $newdate to see if they truly do match?

Comment: yes they do and Dogbert found my issue

Comment: @Mr.1.0 then please accept his answer as correct answer :)

Comment: @Mr. 1.0 So...they shouldn't match then if that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
if ($newdate == $today) {
```

to

```
if ($newDate == $today) {
        ^ this
```

as you're actually declaring `$newDate`.

Comment: I stared at it in disbelief as there was no change, then saw the upvotes and looked closer! IDEs come really helpful to avoid these kinda problems. :) Good catch.

Comment: @SenthilKumar good point, edited answer to make it more obvious :)